# GIF file stops animating in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I have a GIF file that works perfectly fine, but when I open it in Photoshop, it stops animating and all layers change to 1 static image:

[image: Timeline and Layers]

As you can see the Layers section, they all changed!

I didn't even save or export or anything, the moment I open the file in Photoshop, all layers changes! And the funny thing is, I have 116 other GIFs that don't have this problem, it's just this one file!

Here's the file: 
[image: Tired]

Photoshop version: Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I used an online editing tool and resaved the file. The new file was animated in Photoshop and my problem solved!

But I still don't know why? I'll let the question be open for a while, if anyone know what was the reason, please tell me...